# How to use the hosts file to make google.com resolve to bing.com on a single machine

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis-7, reverse-dns, hosts-file

I am having a little trouble understanding how to manipulate the hosts file.  I am using IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 RC2.

How can I make any requests from my machine to google.com resolve to bing.com?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can't you just change the source of the request? Install a new default search provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing has the following IP: 65.55.175.254

So it would be

```
65.55.175.254 google.com www.google.com
```

It will change the url due to redirection on bing's end.. nothing you can do about that

Comment: Flip side, any time bing.com decides to change the IP address, your search will be broken.

Answer (score 4):

Use `nslookup` to find an IP address for bing.com. Then add an entry in your hosts file that looks like:

```
1.2.3.4 google.com www.google.com
```

Replace the IP address with the IP you found for bing.com.

Keep in mind, though, that there's not *one* IP address for any of these services that operate at a massive scale, so the IP address you're getting for bing.com or google.com today may not be in use tomorrow.

Comment: ... or even 20 seconds from now (the TTL on the resource record set visible from here at the time that I write this).